# How does Python internally distinguish "from package import module" between "from module import function"

Tags: python, import, python-internals

If I understand correctly, the python syntax `from ... import ...` can be used in two ways

1. from package-name import module-name
2. from module-name import function-name

I would like to know a bit of how Python *internally* treats the two different forms. Imagine, for example,  that the interpreter gets "from A import B", does the interpreter actually try to determine whether A is a package-name/ module-name, or does it internally treat packages and modules as the same class of objects (something like Linux treats files and directories very similarly)?

Comment: [Python has only one type of module object, and all modules are of this type, regardless of whether the module is implemented in Python, C, or something else. \[..\] It’s important to keep in mind that all packages are modules, but not all modules are packages. Or put another way, packages are just a special kind of module. Specifically, any module that contains a `__path__` attribute is considered a package.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages)...

Comment: The interesting part is not the package/module distinction, which as pointed out is weak: it is the module/function distinction, since one of those can be used even when it (so far) exists only on the disk and one cannot.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, a module is a python file that contains classes and functions. when you say From A Import B python searches for A(a module) in the standard python library and then imports B(the function or class) which is the module if it finds A. If it doesn't it goes out and starts searching in the directory were packages are stored and searches for the package name( A ) and then if it finds it, it imports the Module name(B). If it fails in the past 2 processes it returns an error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer makes me even more confused: what do you mean by "import A from B"? Did you mean "from A import B"?

Comment: sorry I mean from A Import B

Comment: I edited it. I was confused because it is this way in other languages.